# Processing large bitmap images in WPF

Tags: c#

I need to process (change brightness, contrast etc) very large high-quality bitmaps (often over 10MPx) several times per second and need to update it on screen every time ( on Image control in WPF). Currently I'm using AForge.NET library for unmanaged image processing, but there are some problems I cannot solve. First of all, one operation takes ~300ms (without updating the screen) which is not acceptable for me. Here's sample code:

```
UnmanagedImage _img;
BrightnessCorrection _brightness = new BrightnessCorrection();

void Load()
{
   _img = UnmanagedImage.FromManagedImage((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("image.jpg"));
}

void ChangeBrightness(int val) // this method is invoked by changing Slider value - several times per second
{
   _brightness.AdjustValue = val;
   _brightness.ApplyInPlace(_img); // it takes ~300ms for image 22MPx, no screen update - just change brightness "in background"
}
```

I have no experience in image processing, but I think it cannot be much faster since it is very high resolution. Am I right?

Another problem - how to efficiently update the screen? At the moment I have the following (ofc very bad) solution:

```
void ChangeBrightness(int val)
{
   _brightness.AdjustValue = val;
   _brightness.ApplyInPlace(_img);

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Bitmap b = _img.ToManagedImage())
        {
            b.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.StreamSource = ms;
            bmp.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bmp.EndInit();

            MyImageControl.Source = new WriteableBitmap(bmp); // !!!
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, every time new WriteableBitmap is created (you can imagine what is happenin). Instead of these "usings" I tried that way:

```
    WriteableBitmapSource.Lock(); // this object (of type WriteableBitmap) is just MVVM ViewModel's property which is binded to MyImageControl.Source
    WriteableBitmapSource.Source.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, _img.Width, _img.Height), _img.ImageData, _img.Stride * _img.Height * 3, _img.Stride, 0, 0); // image's PixelFormat is 24bppRgb
```

... but WritePixels method throws "Value does not fall within the expected range."  Any ideas why?
Any help will be much appreciated :)

P.S.
Is AForge.NET a good choice at all? Maybe there is better image processing lib?

sorry for my english ;P

Comment: I'd imagine 10MP is your problem - any machine doing that is going to suffer. I've got Photoshop installed and on a 6MP file it takes a moment to change the image contrast/brightness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~300ms for image 22MPx is about 20 ns per pixel. That should be about right.

You need to consider CPU cost and memory access cost.

If you want to improve this further, consider:
1) Use multiple threads, each responsible for a section of the bitmap.
2) Write your own implementation, using SIMD instructions.
3) Do not pre-process the bitmap, transform bitmap scanline when they're needed.